# Flutter set state inside streamBuilder

Tags: flutter, setstate, stream-builder

I just want to update a text for example when my data from stream is completed.

```
if (dataSnapshot.hasData) {
            setState(() {
              showMode = true;
            });
            return Text(Strings.someData,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  fontFamily: "Sofia",
                ));
          } else {
            setState(() {
              showMode = false;
            });
            return Text(Strings.someData,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  fontFamily: "Sofia",
                ));
```

Like this, but the setState cannot be called during build it says. This return for screen is running when user open it. So depending on the stream I want to update some other text with the setState boolean.

My other data is just:

```
showMode ? Widget1() : Widget2()
```

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to call `setState` when you use `StreamBuilder` in this situation. I guess you have this `Text` outside the builder. The solution is to make it part of the builder. Move your `StreamBuilder` up the widget tree

Comment: @Ivo with only 'showMode = true' the ui does not update. And the other widget I want to update is not in the same builder for the ui. The stream only returns one specific widget. And another widget is suppose to listen for the bool only.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. Make it part of the builder. You won't need to have a boolean then and let the other text also check the snapshot itself. If necessary make the StreamBuilder the top element in this statefulwidget

Comment: @Ivo ok, but the widgets are two complete different things in the ui, so I can't wrap it I think and return both the text and the widget from same builder? The widget has its own positioning and same with the text.

Comment: Your entire page structure would be under the builder, not only the texts. It's just moving the builder up the widget tree

Comment: @Robban13 can please share complete code for better understanding.

Comment: @DannyRufus How can I do that?

Comment: you can edit the post and share the snippet of the code where you are using the showMode and the snippet where you are using StreamBuilder.